# What is 656 Beagle?

Tags: astronomy, solar-system

What kind of object is [656 Beagle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/656_Beagle) ([1908BU](http://comets.universetoday.com/l/3668/656-Beagle-1908-BU))?

I know it's a minor planet, but that includes a large array of different stuff. Specifically, I am looking at the general chemistry/geology of the object.

Comment: This is really an astronomy question, not a physics question.

Comment: I nominate for reopening based on astronomy being on-topic now. (And besides, astronomy has been physics since before physics was physics by several millennia ;) But if people think it is still too localized, then don't bother reopening.

Comment: @ChrisWhite: Could be too localized, but meh. Reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

656 Beagle is a small (~53 km diameter) asteroid with a 3.15 AU semimajor axis. It's luminosity is very faint, with H = 9.92. Nothing seems to be known about its geologic basis, but it certainly does not possess a measurable atmosphere. See http://occsec.wellington.net.nz/planet/2008/updates/080912_656_19331_u.htm for more information.